# Is it usually better to establish hosting for a domain based email account with a domain registrar or web host?

Tags: dns, domain-registrar, email-accounts

When a domain registrar and a website hoster are not the same entity, than generally a website owner can choose on which of the two to establish a Domain Based Email Account (DBEA).

There can be pros and cons to choosing between establishing a DBEA on a domain registrar to establishing a DBEA on a website hoster (especially in the context of migration) and I want to know which of the two is generally considered a better approach and why.

Is there a standard among webmasters about where it's best to establish a DBEA and why (domain registrar or website hoster)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a website and email for a domain name you generally have to purchase four services:

- Domain registration
- DNS hosting
- Website hosting
- Email hosting

Each of those four could be with separate companies.   It is almost always possible to transfer any of those services to any other company without affecting the other services.

If you want to host your email with your domain registrar, that is fine.  You could move your email hosting later without affecting your domain registration.  You could transfer your domain registration later without affecting your email hosting.

If you want to host your email with your web site host, that is fine.   You could move your email hosting later without affecting your web hosting.  You could move your web hosting later without affecting your email hosting.

Hosting your email with any 3rd party host that specializes in just email hosting would also be fine.  I would usually recommend this route unless you get a good bundled price with your domain registration or web hosting.

Here is a diagram of how it is set up in DNS ([source](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100730/i-want-to-use-email-service-of-zoho-mail-with-hosting-server-hostinger-for-my-cu)):

[image]

Transferring your email hosting is usually a matter of:

- Moving all the emails from one system to another (this is the hardest part)
- Changing the DNS records to point to the new host.  The MX records are the main ones, but there are usually TXT records that verify which servers are allowed to send email from the domain, and there may be subdomain records such as `mail.example.com` as well.
- Reconfiguring all email clients to check and read email at the new host (often the second hardest part).

Transferring email hosting is enough of a pain that you don't want to do it on a whim.  However, you shouldn't have to worry about vendor-lock-in with your web host or domain registrar when you do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single standard and no single better answer - it comes down to your needs and who can best provide them. I would err on the side of your registrar or even another party for email if I could not ascertain the hosting providers expertise.

Some web hosting providers will just bang your accounts onto the same box as your web hosting. (Often in conjunction with cPanel)  IMHO this is a bad idea because it reduces security of your web hosting and email hosting by having them in 1 server.  It also means the service provider is less likely to properly look after email - and mail service should be centralised as there is an amount if upkeep you dont want to duplicate. **web providers that offer separate email servers are probably an OK option**

On the flip side you often can get better support and flexibility through a web provider.

A third option is to give your nail to a large provider to handle. As a very, very rough rule, the bigger the provider the better the spam filtering and competence - and running a mail service competently is harder then running web hosting competently.